# SmartAdmin no longer available

Tags: angular, smartadmin

It seems that Wrapbootstrap SmartAdmin template is now no longer available. Anybody know if this template will come back under new packaging?

Comment: I also noticed the same. I bought the template and referenced back to it every now and then. Here is another link to view it, but seems you cant buy from there either as it redirects back to wrapbootstrap : https://bootdey.com/themes/view/SmartAdmin-Responsive-WebApp-Frontend

Comment: Looks like they gave up. The template was not well designed and there were tons of typescript errors.

Comment: I've been using SA for 10 months. Most of the TS errors were simple mass conversions, e.g. convert == to ===. Took me less than an hour to fix all such errors. Since then SA has worked very well for me. Many great features. They sold over 49K licenses. I'll keep using it. I don't need much support, but do like to collaborate with other SA devs, so a forum of some sort would be nice.

Comment: I hope nothing bad has happened to the guy, because his Twitter account has disappeared as well. It was: https://twitter.com/myorangeca?lang=en .. now it's gone. Poof! Just like that. Either he's just not interested in giving any explanation or something bad may have happened to him. I hope the latter is not the case.

Comment: @Matt He now seems to go under "@myplaneticket" - But there is no activity. It seems one of his friends(or colleagues) "@ashobiz" has tweeted a lot about wrapbootstrap not paying them, so I suspect that is why it was pulled. I agree with BobC - I am also using it, and even with the few minor issues, its a great tool and has a lot of really great features! I am also still using it.

Comment: @AxleWack I agree; IMHO SmartAdmin is the best bootstrap based admin theme out there. I was seriously looking forward to the update for Bootstrap 4. His last post was earlier this year and seemed to indicate he was very close to finishing it. If I recall correctly, he said that if you own the theme, you could message him to ask for a preview version for testing the BS4 update. Very frustrating that it seems to have all been lost now.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the seller was on vacation. All he did was make the theme unavailable. According to him, it was because he wasn't going to be around for a couple of weeks and couldn't provide support.

He/She probably didn't want to seem unresponsive. But it gave a lot of us a scare. The theme is back and normal as can be. An update was actually just released.

*Edit:*

*Link to the theme: https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-WB0573SK0*